# Closing Liferay dialog box programmatically

Tags: javascript, dialog, liferay-6

I have Liferay dialog box, I want to close this dialog box and wish to redirect my url to a page.

I am doing it this way.

```
<aui:column columnWidth="16" >

<%if(UserGroupRoleLocalServiceUtil.hasUserGroupRole(u.getUserId(), groupId, role.getRoleId())){ %>

<input value="delete" type="button"  onclick="document.location.href='
<portlet:actionURL name="deleteUserRole"><portlet:param name="memberId" value="<%= memberIdStr %>"/>
<portlet:param name="organization" value="<%=  Long.toString(organizationID) %>"/></portlet:actionURL>'"  />
    <%} %>
            </aui:column>


public void deleteUserRole(ActionRequest actionRequest,ActionResponse actionResponse){

// process to delete user role

    Role r = RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRole(org.getCompanyId(),
                    "Power User");


    UserGroupRoleLocalServiceUtil.deleteUserGroupRoles(userID, groupId, new long[] { r.getRoleId() });

        actionResponse.sendRedirect("/group/employee/empHome");                 


}
```

By using this way when I click on delete button this method gets call, perform process and it redirects to this url but withing popup window.

I want to redirect to given page in actionResponse.sendRedirect page but not in dialog box, it should not open in dailog box.

**How can I close this dialog box first and then redirect my page to given url?**

I am opening dialog box by calling this class on a link 
Below is my js file

/*test.js*/

```
 var myPopup;
AUI().ready( function() {

    if (AUI().one('#testing-menu')) {

    AUI().one('.extendClick').on(
        'mouseenter',
        function(event){
            AUI().one('.navi-type').setStyles({'display': 'none'});
            AUI().one('.extendClick').setStyles({'display': 'none'});
            AUI().one('.collapseArrow').setStyles({'display': 'block'});
        }
      );


   AUI().all('.employee-dialog').on(
        'click',
        function(event){
          var url = event.currentTarget.get('href');
          event.preventDefault();
          //console.info(url);

        window.myPopup= Liferay.Util.openWindow(
              {
                dialog: {
                  align: { points: ['tc', 'tc'] },
                  width: 960
                },
                title: 'Settings',
                uri: url
              }
            );
        }
      );


  }
});
```

Comment: How do you open your dialog popup? Show that code please.

Comment: @GaborSch I have added code for popup dialog box

Answer (score 2):

Save the popup reference, and use that to close the popup later:

```
var myPopup;
AUI().all('.employee-dialog').on(
    'click',
    function(event){
      [..]
      myPopup = Liferay.Util.openWindow([...]);
    }
  );
```

Use the saved popup reference in `onclick`:

```
<input value="delete" type="button" onclick="myPopup.close();document.location.href='
    [...]
```

Comment: I have added variable `myPopup` in my js file just above employee-dialog function and then tried to call it on onclick as per shown you, but its neither closing popup or not even calling my `<portlet:actionURL` method on this onclick button

Comment: It may be a visibility issue. Declare `myPopup` on the top level, so you would have an access to it in the `onclick` anonymous block.

Comment: Yes ,I have added this variable at top of the file,but when I am clicking on button it's not calling my <portlet:actionURL method nor myPopup.close()

Comment: Actually it's giving me error in firebug error mode as ReferenceError:myPopup is not defined.

I have defined js file in another portlet and I am calling it from another portlet, is it reason so we are getting this error?

Comment: @Ran Maybe. Try to define on window level: `window.myPopup = ...` and `window.myPopup.close()`

Comment: I have tried this way also but in firebug(mozilla) I am getting error as TypeError:window.myPopup is undefined

Comment: Try to debug your code, set breakpoints both at setting and reading the property. This may give you a better overview what's going on, unfortunately I cannot say anything.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am able to close this dialog box in this way.

```
<input value="delete" type="button"  onclick="javascript:closePopUp;document.location.href='
<portlet:actionURL name="deleteUserRole"><portlet:param name="memberId" value="<%= memberIdStr %>"/>
<portlet:param name="organization" value="<%=  Long.toString(organizationID) %>"/></portlet:actionURL>'"  />





<script type="text/javascript">
function closePopUp(){
top.document.getElementById('closethick').click();
}
</script>
```